# Send a HTTP POST request in Lua 5.0 (preferably without installing packages)

Tags: lua

I'm new to Lua and only picked it up after I found out you can use Lua to add scripts to the game Zoo Tycoon 2. However, Zoo Tycoon 2 uses Lua version 5.0.2 and I haven't managed to get LuaRocks to work with Lua 5.0.

I tried it with LuaSocket for Lua 5.1, but it didn't work and I don't know what went wrong, as I don't know when my script throws exceptions because the game doesn't give me feedback other than what my script was supposed to do not happening. I've tried logging to a console window or a file, but that didn't work either, but that might be something for another question.

I've looked at [How to HTTP POST in Lua without using Lua Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043174/how-to-http-post-in-lua-without-using-lua-socket) but I couldn't find documentation on the `tcpConnect()`, `tcpSend()` and `tcpClose()` functions used there and I don't know where those come from or if they are compatible with Lua 5.0.

I think it's probably the best for me to have as little dependencies as possible. So, I was wondering, how do you send a HTTP POST request in Lua 5.0?

Comment: Can you run `os.execute("curl")`?

Comment: I'll give it a try later. I have come with bad tidings though, it appears that the Zoo Tycoon 2 devs have removed some methods from standard Lua libraries (explaining why I couldn't write to a file), I expect the restrictions on scripts for this game to be heavy.